# Problem with too many faces of object

Tags: rendering, modeling

I make my object complex so that i can paint real circle in part of his body but when i decimate it my circle look terrible. I don't know what to use to make this circle stabile and make my object with less polygons as possible. . Now I have 766 000 faces and that is not acceptable. Please help. (sry for my bad english)

I have one more question. I tried to use f brush to point out his water gun but is there a better way to get punched his wather gun?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use geometry to paint colors. Use a texture map for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to make the colors directly dependent on the topology of the object (there are exceptions, of course).

Instead you should use a [*Texture*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures).

A texture is usually an image which is mapped to the surface of your object based on a [UV map](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping). There are other kinds of textures and mapping techniques as well, e.g. *Procedural textures*.
However, in this case you probably want to UV unwrap and use an image texture.

For example, I can *UV unwrap* this sphere:

[image]

and then texture it with this image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

As you can see, the texture is not dependent on the topology of the mesh.

I recommend you check out some tutorials on texturing and UV unwrapping in blender. There are many good sources out there (google is your friend), but here are a couple of places to start with:

- [Blender Cookie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ha2rFR6qO0)
- [Blender Guru](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/the-secrets-of-realistic-texturing/)
- [The Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping)

Also check the [beginner's reference](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/43/599) on meta.